# eBook format in nowadays: EPUB is de facto standard?

Tags: language-agnostic

The output format choice is an essential decision in any software project. I have projects for distribution of  digital content for  eBook customers, and ideally, we offer downloads for only one format... Plus one format is "plus cost", for software and content revision.

1. That format, today, is EPUB?
2. Better offer more than one format in nowadays?

---

There was a "format war" (or a "Tower of eBabel") for ebooks, who won?

[Wikipedia says that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-book_formats)   "*... some eBook formats are demonstrably more popular, and more widely supported than others. The EPUB format is the most widely supported (...) that is, it is supported by the largest number of e-Readers*".

So, putting in other words:

1. **EPUB is a consensus?** It is the most popular, for ebook readers today?
2. **And about the "second place" (PDF?), what is the format? This second format is still important for ebook readers?**  There are reliable and updated statistics? ([2010 example](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/07/20/e-book-formats/))

Comment: moved to [*ebooks.stackexchange* with same title](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/2418/2531), see good answers there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This content [has been transferred to eBooks.stackexchange](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/a/8768/2531), please EDIT AND COLLABORE THERE... Here will be deleted.

---

I did my homework. Some up-to-date results and conceptual analysis.

### Concepts

As used here:

- *e-book* and *e-book reader*: [e-book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-book) is the content, a file, and the *e-reader* is the device, a hardware.
- *e-reader*: considering here that an e-reader is a "[paper substitute](http://www.ecolibris.net/ebooks.asp)" device, so a Desktop PC computer or an iPhone are not e-readers, but a [Tablet computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tablet_computer) is.
- "*usable e-book format*": in a broader sense, paper-oriented formats, like *[PostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript)* or *[PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format)*, are acceptable for e-books, and can be called *e-book formats*.
- real, strict sense **e-book format**: neither a "web format", like HTML, nor a "paper format", like PDF. E-Books are "[paged media](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/)", as paper books, but with diagramming flexibility: an e-book need to be [reflowable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflowable_document), a resizable content that adapts to different resolutions and different [aspect-radio screens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image)). 
  PS: HTML is not an ebook format because is not "all in a only one file".
- "interactive e-book format": another growing demand for e-books are interactivity ([EPUB example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuHuotsUxyE) ), but we can ignore this demand here, in favor of the strict sense, and the necessity of [classic books](http://www.gutenberg.org/) into digital devices.

So, conceptually, PDF is considered an (usable) *e-book format* because it is a legacy from old paper-oriented systems, where authors and layout designers were oriented to the paper size. As of 2012 the screen of the "e-book reader" is the final recipient of the content, and layout authoring is oriented to (some) screen adaptability.

There are three important criteria — metrics to check if a format is *de facto* standard — for electing e-book format popularity:

- most widely **supported formats**: between popular e-book readers, statistics about direct support (without content loss or conversion demand) for each format.
- more **downloads**: sales and download counting, in reliable "sales statistics" at bookstores and download statistics at libraries.
- **availability**: number of distinct online links (at online libraries and others), each link to a distinct file download of a public domain e-book. Example: number of titles into the [Project](http://www.gutenberg.org/), [SciELO](http://www.scielo.org/), etc.

### Results

Supposing reliable information (see sources),

- *supported formats* (by tablets plus strict e-readers): PDF and EPUB. I kick around ~90% PDF, ~80% EPUB.
- *downloads* (only e-book sales, global): PDF, EPUB and (only USA market) MOBI. I kick around ~50% PDF, ~40% EPUB.
- *availability* (only public domain e-books): PDF and EPUB. I kick around ~90% PDF and TXT, only ~10% EPUB.

**CONCLUSION**:

- if my software problem is "*what e-book formats to offer*", I need to check my public. **For non-USA public, EPUB is the only format**. For USA public, EPUB and MOBI. 
  NOTE: it is for "*e-book demand*", but, check your public and their necessities. Nowadays, a printed book is also a necessity, people still like to use paper. PDF (with adequate paper size) may be a good option for generic (paper plus e-book) demands.
- if my problem is "*what e-book formats to accept*" (ex. Receiving e-books to build a library), there are more options, and some conversion problems to solve with software.
- if there are no software problem, is only to say "the standard is" or "the most popular is". You can say: "the most disponible is PDF", "the most acceptable are PDF and EPUB", and, **in strict sense, EPUB is the most popular, the *de facto* standard e-book format**.

### Sources

(Please edit here to correct or to add more sources)

Supposed to reliable/medium/informal sources by context (formal/informal), databases (general/strict), etc.

1. **Reliable sources**

1.1. [Wikipedia Comparison of e-book formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-book_formats): show that EPUB and PDF are the most widely supported formats.

1.2. [Indicated as reliable by Wikipedia at market share information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-book#Market_shares):

```
  1.2.1. Goldman Sachs 2010 report cited by [Quantity market shares of e-book sales in US](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2011-03-22/barnes-noble-is-said-to-be-likely-to-end-search-for-buyer-without-a-sale.html): with Amazon (58%) and Barnes&Noble (27%) dominating. Amazon offers MOBI, the others EPUB.

  1.2.2. [Market share of e-readers in Canada by Ipsos Reid at January 2012](http://www.ipsos-na.com/news-polls/pressrelease.aspx?id=5399): Kobo 46% (EPUB), Amazon 24%  (MOBI) and Sony 18% (EPUB) dominating.
```

1.3. With sources [cited by Wikipedia, at *Tablet computer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tablet_computer), "As of October 2012, the top-selling tablet is Apple's iPad with 100 million units sold, (...) followed by Amazon's Kindle Fire with 7 million, Barnes and Noble's Nook 5 million, and Google's Nexus 7 with 3 million units.": Apple, Nook and Nexus are EPUB, so **EPUB represent more than 95% of Tablet market** (and MOBI less than 5%).

1.4. [SciELO Library](http://www.scielo.org/): in November 2012 there were 377772 (378 thousand) articles in PDF and EPUB format.

2. **Informal sources**

2.1. [Project Gutenberg Library](http://www.gutenberg.org): over 40000 (40 thousand) books in TXT, and less into other formats, including EPUB and MOBI.

2.2. [Smashwords bookstore 2010 statistics](http://blog.smashwords.com/2010/02/most-popular-ebook-formats-revealed.html): counting selling/download, 35% PDF, 22% EPUB, 15% MOBI, 9% TXT.

2.3. [O'Reilly bookstore 2009 statistic](http://toc.oreilly.com/2009/01/format-comparison-pdf-epub-and-mobi-downloads-from-ebook-bundles.html): shows PDF and EPUB dominating.

2.4. [Manybooks bookstore online statistics, counting since 2009](http://manybooks.net/format_stats.php): PDF (24%), EPUB (22%) and MOBI (10%) dominate.

Answer (score 0):

EPUB and MOBI (Kindle). Why do you want to offer only one format? Conversion from EPUB to MOBI is in the best case a single invocation of `kindlegen`.

Comment: Thanks, a first clue!  Well, another question about convertions at readers... If EPUB is a *de facto* standard, why not Kindle incorporates KindleGen?

Comment: @PeterKrauss I don't exactly understand your question. Amazon has made a political/business decision not to support EPUB, the background and implications of which are beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes @torazaburo, you are correct ... Well, I see that [starting from Kindle 2 now support PDF natively](http://blogkindle.com/2009/06/kindle-dx-pdf-support-review/)... If Kindle is so important reader, the decision is about "PDF *vs* MOBI"... Need to see statistics.